# Set image and text of list view item in another imageview and textview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an array of images and string like this:

```
String[] stations = new String[] {
            "GHOTKI 91 Radio FM","UmerKot 91.4 Radio","TMK 100.20 Radio"
};

public static int [] images ={R.drawable.ghotkifmlogo,R.drawable.umerkotfmlogo,R.drawable.tmkfmlogo};
```

In an custom listview how can I replace these in another Image view and texview?

I need to change that imageview and textview everytime with the clicked item's image and text.

Here's my Custom Adapter:

```
public class TrackAdapter extends  BaseAdapter{
    String [] description;
    Context context;
    int [] imageId;

    public TrackAdapter(Context c, String[] d, int[] prgmImages) {

        description=d;
        context= c;
        imageId=prgmImages;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return description.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cardviewlayout,null);
        }
        //get the textview and set its text
        TextView tv=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tracktitle);
        //get the img view and set its img icon
        ImageView im=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trackimage);

        tv.setText(description[position]);
        im.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Here's Main Activity:

```
private TextView mSelectedTrackTitle;
    private ImageView mSelectedTrackImage;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private ImageView mPlayerControl;
    ListView lv_tracks;
    TrackAdapter track_adapter;

    String[] stations = new String[] {
            "GHOTKI 91 Radio FM","UmerKot 91.4 Radio","TMK 100.20 Radio"
    };
     public static int [] images ={R.drawable.ghotkifmlogo,R.drawable.umerkotfmlogo,R.drawable.tmkfmlogo};



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();



        //get a reference to our ListView so we can associate it with our custom ArrayAdapter
        lv_tracks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.track_list);
        //create a new CustomAdapter
        track_adapter =new TrackAdapter(this,stations,images);
        lv_tracks.setAdapter(track_adapter);//connect the ListView with myCustomAdapter

        //Want to set selected image and title here in these
        mSelectedTrackTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selected_track_title);
        mSelectedTrackImage =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.selected_track_image);
lv_tracks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
??
}
```

Do not really understand what to do with onitemselect here .
in order to change image and text.

Comment: do you want to move to  the  next item in onItem click

Comment: No, i want to replace the imageview and textview(currently with no image source and text respectively) with the clicked item's image and text . Whenever it is clicked.

Comment: you can get it by using  listview `OnItemClickListener` for this and it returns position of Item clicked then you can use this position as your desired operation

Comment: Yes. I'm not getting how to set ? Thats actually my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    mSelectedTrackTitle.setText( stations[position] );
    mSelectedTrackImage.setImageResource( images[positions] );
}
```

It will get the station name and image from the clicked position in your arrays, and update your views.

Answer (score 1):

you can get current item position  by using listview **OnItemClickListener**   it will returns **position of an  Item clicked** then you can use this position as your desired operation

```
   lv_tracks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
        mSelectedTrackTitle.setText(stations[position]);
    mSelectedTrackImage.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,images [position])); 
   // or 
        mSelectedTrackImage.setImageResource(images [position]);
        }
```

Comment: OMG . Thank You!! Working great .

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this:

```
lv_tracks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          mSelectedTrackTitle.setText(stations[position]);
          mSelectedTrackImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
       }
```